# Error opening database sqlite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have a problem with opening database sqlite in android. I got this error `"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"` on code that i open the database. Please help me correct this...

I updated the code. Now i separate the code.
The DBHelper class

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DBName = "db_reminder.db";
public static final String TableName = "task_table";
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
public static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";
public static final String RADIUS = "radius";
public static final String ALAMAT = "alamat";
public static final String KONTEKS_TUGAS = "konteks_tugas";
public static final String makeTable = "create table "
    + TableName + "("
    + ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
    + LATITUDE + " integer not null,"
    + LONGITUDE + " integer not null,"
    + RADIUS + " integer not null,"
    + ALAMAT + " varchar(50) not null,"
    + KONTEKS_TUGAS + " varchar(50) not null"
    + ");";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("db", "create table");
    db.execSQL(makeTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("db", "upgrade table");
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TableName);
}
}
```

The DBReminder class

```
public class DBReminder {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private DBHelper helper;
private Context konteks;

public DBReminder(Context c) {
    this.konteks = c;
    helper = new DBHelper(c);
}

public void openWrite() throws SQLException {
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void openRead() throws SQLException {
    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
}

public void closeConn() {
    helper.close();
}

public void insertTask(Task tugas) {
    openWrite();
    ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
    val.put(helper.LATITUDE, tugas.getLatitude());
    val.put(helper.LONGITUDE, tugas.getLongitude());
    val.put(helper.RADIUS, tugas.getRadius());
    val.put(helper.ALAMAT, tugas.getAlamat());
    val.put(helper.KONTEKS_TUGAS, tugas.getKonteks());
    db.insert(helper.TableName, null, val);
    closeConn();
}}
```

Code in activity

```
public void cekPosisi(String txtAlamat) {
    if (txtAlamat.toString().length() > 0) {
        dbHandler.openRead();
        String sql = "select * from task_table where alamat = '"+txtAlamat+"';";
        Cursor rs = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if(rs != null) {
            rs.moveToFirst();
            String addr = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("alamat"));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Anda ada tugas di " + addr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Anda tidak ada tugas di lokasi sekarang", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        rs.close();
        dbHandler.closeConn();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tidak ada alamat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And i use in

```
txtAddr = teksAlamat.getText().toString();
    this.cariTugas.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("alamat textView", txtAddr);
            cekPosisi(txtAddr);
        }
    });
```

I updated the code but still same error nullException. Please help.

Comment: Which line gives the null pointer?

Comment: you should put the logcat also so some one could help you

Comment: and have you initialized konteks (context)

Comment: in this part dbHandler.openRead();

Comment: @AviKumarManku yes i have initialized

Comment: Don't use Varchar(nn) in Sqlite, use the TEXT datatype instead.

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

I really recommend you change your `openRead()` method signature to:

```
public DBReminder openRead(Context c) throws SQLException {
   helper = new DBHelper(c);
   db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
   return this;
}
```

and then

```
db = dbHandler.openRead(YourActivity.this);
String sql = "select * from task_table where alamat = '"+txtAlamat+"';";
Cursor rs = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Because your problem is most likely related that your `Context` is assigned to **`NULL`**.

Comment: Should i add it to this function to:
public DBReminder openWrite() throws SQLException {
  helper = new DBHelper(konteks);
  db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this;
 }

Comment: @user2214226 for openWrite() method same, `openWrite(Context c)`

Comment: You mean this: dbHandler.openRead(); it's in activity for query that i posted

Comment: It doesn't work too. I code the openWrite() not using SQLiteDatabase. But when i try to use it, it's give me a same error

Comment: @IvanAhmed you are doing it wrong simply said. look again at my asnwer and do same like I. you need to call `db = dbHandler.openRead(YourActivity.this);`

Comment: I've do this: db = dbHandler.openRead(viewMap.this); but still error.
How?

Comment: @IvanAhmed so something you are doing wrong. it works for me. viewMap is Activity?

Comment: Yes it's a activity extends MapActivity.
Thanks for the help

Comment: @IvanAhmed probably you need to change app logic, what is DBReminder? add here its java code.

Comment: The openWrite() is fine not using SQLiteDatabase. But when i change the openWrite and openRead to SQLiteDatabase it comes error. Before change to your updated answer, openWrite is fine and openRead does'nt work

Comment: @IvanAhmed add to your post laso openWrite method.

Comment: @IvanAhmed how i mentioned. you did it wrong. did you check my answer? i wrote you that you need to use `dbHandler.openRead(Context c);` what you don't understand? what is confusing? i don't see where you are intialising your db variable...

Comment: Sorry i copy the wrong code. Now you see i add dbHandler.openRead(viewMap.this);

Comment: @IvanAhmed where you are intialising db variable?

Comment: In viewMap activity same class with dbHandler.openRead(viewMap.this);